# Set height of element to height of neighbouring element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a GUI in WPF application which looks like that:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="2"></Border>

            <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" Height="90" Margin="2"></Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="2">
            <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Some"/>
                <Button Content="Buttons"/>
            </StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Some Label"/>
                <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ListViewItem>Item1</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
                    <!-- and so on...-->
                    <ListViewItem>Item8</ListViewItem>
                    </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

The two borders to the left are just placeholders for the GUI elements in the real application. The GUI element looks like this:

[image]

I want the right `StackPanel` to be just as high as the left `StackPanel`, like in the following screenshot:

[image]

For the screenshot, I was manually setting the `MaxHeight` property of the `ListView` to right value, but of course that is no satisfying solution and it will become impossible if I don't know at compile time which and how many elements populate the left `StackPanel`.

Is there any solution to this Problem? I was trying a binding:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="Left">
                <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="2"></Border>

                <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" Height="90" Margin="2"></Border>
            </StackPanel>

            <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="2" Height="{Binding ElementName=Left, Path=Height}">
                <!-- as above -->
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

But I did not succeed with it, also when I bind to the `ActualHeight` of the left `StackPanel`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack panels expand to fit their contents. Instead you need to put the ListView in a container of a fixed size (I've used a Grid with a row of height `*`), that takes its size from the boxes in the first column.

I used a binding to `ActualHeight`, that was very similar to yours.

The other important difference was setting `VerticalAlignment="Top"` on the first stack panel, otherwise it automatically sizes to the same height as the border.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="2"></Border>
            <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" Height="90" Margin="2"></Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <Border Height="{Binding ElementName=Left, Path=ActualHeight}" >
            <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="2">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Some"/>
                        <Button Content="Buttons"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Label  Grid.Row="1" Content="Some Label"/>
                    <ListView Grid.Row="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ListViewItem>Item1</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
                        <!-- and so on...-->
                        <ListViewItem>Item8</ListViewItem>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but unfortunately I doesn't help me much. I have to give the row of the outer grid a fixed size, which I don't want to, because than I have to know the size of the left `StackPanel` at compile time .

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I've updated my answer to use a binding. There's still something slightly odd in the margins, but I don't think it'll be a big problem.

Comment: Thanks, that is an improvement. I hope that the issue with the margins can be solved.

Comment: The issue with the margins is actually because you've set a background colour and margin on the contents of the first column, but on the container in the second column. I've updated the answer to add an inner border, which makes the two columns line up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Width="300" Height="200">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="2"></Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="2"></Border>
        </Grid>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Beige" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="2">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="Some"/>
                    <Button Content="Buttons"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Some Label"/>
                <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ListViewItem>Item1</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
                    <!-- and so on...-->
                    <ListViewItem>Item8</ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel
        Name="FirstPanel" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <Border 
            Background="Beige" 
            BorderThickness="1" 
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Width="100" 
            Height="50" 
            Margin="2"/>

        <Border 
            Background="Beige" 
            BorderThickness="1" 
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Width="100" 
            Height="90" 
            Margin="2"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <Border 
        Name="ContainerBorder"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Background="Beige" 
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        Margin="2"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=FirstPanel, Path=ActualHeight}">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Some"/>
                <Button Content="Buttons"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Some Label"/>

            <ListView Grid.Row="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ListViewItem>Item1</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item3</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item4</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item5</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item6</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item7</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item8</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Output:

[image]